# Jquery for iterating through a 2D Array and then placing the value in a HTML DIV

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, json

I am attempting to create a "Jeopardy" (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeopardy!‎
) style game. The way that I have this set up is a 5 x 5 matrix or multidimensional array. I am trying to write a code that will iterate through each array and then place the value into another HTML DIV.

Here is my code:

Jquery:

```
var clues = new Array ();
    [0] [0] = "On the world political map, where were some of the major states and empires located about 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?";
    [0] [1] = "What were the artistic, literary, and intellectual ideas of the Renaissance?";
    [0] [2] = "Where were the five world religions located around 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?";
    [0] [3] = "What were the regional trading patterns about 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?";
    [0] [4] = "Why were the regional trading patterns important?";

   $.each(clues, function(){
       $("#rowOne").append('<li>' +value+ '</li>'); 
       ('li').on('click','a', function(){
            var foo = $(this).text();
            $('#clueContainer').text(clues [foo]);
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="rowOne" class="center">
    <li><a href="#">$100</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$100</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$100</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$100</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">$100</a></li>
</ul>
```

New DIV:

```
   <div id="clueContainer" class="center"></div>
```

However, when I run the code nothing shows up in the new HTML DIV.

Can some one please help?

Comment: Have a look at your javascript console.  You will find that you have many syntax errors.

Comment: You never build your array. And why do you need a 2D array for this anyway?

Comment: This is because I have five rows and five columns. I only posted one row, I assume that the rest of the rows will be similar in code.

Comment: @justLearning, you might *think* you've posted one row. As James Montagne said, you have many syntax errors, and that is why, as j08691 points out, you never build your array.

Comment: @justLearning, your latest edit is even crazier. Would you consider a basic JS tutorial?

Comment: could you please point me to one that addresses this specific function?

Comment: Do you have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use a two-dimensional array, I recommend using an array of objects. Each object would represent a category. A property of each category object would be an array of clues.

```
var categories = [
    {
        name: 'Category 1',
        clues: [
            'clue 1',
            'clue 2',
            'clue 3'
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Category 2',
        clues: [
            'clue 1',
            'clue 2',
            'clue 3'
        ]
    }
];

// The length of this array matches the lengths of the clue arrays.
var values = ['$100', '$200', '$300'];
```

You can iterate through them like this:

```
$.each(categories, function(i, category) {
    alert('Category: ' + category.name);
    $.each(category.clues, function(i, clue) {
        alert('Clue: ' + clue + ', value=' + values[i]);
    });
});
```

BTW: It's not really Jeopardy if you phrase the clues as questions.

Comment: FYI, that was a joke and I actually upvoted, not down... no idea why someone would downvote this.

Comment: @James Montagne - I got the joke. I actually considered phrasing it as a question, but it wouldn't have been easy.

Comment: This works, but I would like to take the values and place them into the '#clueContainer' DIV - not in a 'alert' box.

Comment: I was just showing how to iterate through the data structure. The alerts are there only to show how you can access the data. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/4nPZj/) that shows how you can use the data to generate elements.

Comment: I believe that this will work. I just need to add in the code to match my HTML code.

Answer (score 5):

You need to change a few things in this:

```
$.each(clues, function(){
//                     ^-------------------------------- No params given
   $("#rowOne").append('<li>' +value+ '</li>'); 
//                             ^------------------------ Undefined
   ('li').on('click','a', function(){
// ^---------------------------------------------------- Syntax Error, missing $
//        ^--------------------------------------------- Why each loop run?
        var foo = $(this).text();
        $('#clueContainer').text(clues [foo]);
//                                     ^---------------- Space???
    });
});
```

The right one, updated code would be:

```
$.each(clues[0], function(index, value){
   $("#rowOne").append('<li>' +value+ '</li>'); 
});
$('li').on('click','a', function(){
   var foo = $(this).text();
   $('#clueContainer').text(clues[foo]);
});
```

---

There's also another serious problem. The way you build the array is not the right one in **JavaScript**. You have to replace it this way:

```
var clues = [
                [
                    "On the world political map, where were some of the major states and empires located about 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?",
                    "What were the artistic, literary, and intellectual ideas of the Renaissance?",
                    "Where were the five world religions located around 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?",
                    "What were the regional trading patterns about 1500 A.D. (C.E.)?",
                    "Why were the regional trading patterns important?"
                ]
            ];
```

---

In my opinion, it is wise to use JSON format for storing this, instead of arrays. JSON format is multidimensional. As [John S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/859640/john-s)'s answer has the JSON format, you can take it from that!

Comment: You left off the biggest problem.  The array "building".

Comment: You've got some issues in your updated code.  The callback to `each` has a first parameter passed which is the index, not the element.  The 2nd param is the element.  Also, you can't just `each` over a "2d" array like that.  `value` would be an array.  And your array building wont' work like that.

Comment: @JamesMontagne See if this works? Well, I replaced `clues` with `clues[0]`... :P

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing, but may I know the reason for the downvote? Should I improve the answer in any way?

Comment: The last bit about creating the array is still really broken.  That might be it.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Yup! My bad. Multidimensional arrays are not present in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your question - you need to iterate over 2D array, so you need to do 2 for each loop simultaneously to get the value. BTW in your given code - array population is not syntactically correct also.

Comment: what I have done wrong guys... is there anything wrong I have mentioned here. pls let me know my mistake for this down voting. You people are doing the same thing what I told earlier...

Comment: We all got downvoted. I don't think you said anything that was incorrect.